# Stream 1TB GZIP From S3, decompress upload to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, gzip

i have big data stored in S3, i need to decompress the GZ file and obviously can't do this in S3.

I have achieved this with streaming (via a EC2 and local) large tar archives in S3 but not with single gzip file, below works with tar gz archives but its likely as the files were smaller (38GB * 100 files) maybe?

```
aws s3 cp s3://test/test.tar.gz - | tar -xz --to-command='aws s3 cp - s3://test/test_$TAR_REALNAME'
```

To try with the single gzip file i I ran:

```
aws s3 cp s3://test/test/csv.gz - | gzip -d | aws s3 cp - s3://test/test.csv
```

and i got a process killed error on my EC2

I added

```
--expected-size 4000000000000
```

but it still kills the process.

I tried locally with:

```
gzip -d ./test.csv.gz - | aws s3 cp s3://test/test.csv
```

but it still does not work, it was so easy with the Tar archive..

Is there any AWS CLI based way to do this easy or am i missing something obvious?

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message that you're getting, and what instance type are you running on? Please edit your question with the answer.

Comment: If you're running on a small instance `t2.micro` or `t2.nano`, you probably don't have enough memory to buffer the stream. With an expected output size of 4 TB (which may be low, depending on your source data), you will need approximately a 1/2 GB buffer.

Comment: What size instance would i need? i'm on a T2.Medium.
I thought it would have been fine since i could use tar to unpack 1TB compressed of over 100 38GB files and that worked perfectly.

I'm trying to keep it in AWS to do this fast rather then do it locally

Comment: No idea. It depends on what's failing, but since you haven't updated your question with the actual error, nobody can tell you. You could always try ever-greater instance sizes until it works.

Comment: You should probably also try running `top` during the download to see which of the processes has the biggest memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

1. --multi-part-upload
2. configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 20 (default is 10)
   You will get the desired result you want.

For reference, please use this link:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/